# Как получить функцию с параметрами React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx, react-hook

Мне нужно сделать форму с использованием React Hooks, стейт Redux я достаю вот так:

```
const searchValue = useSelector(state => state.Search.searchValue);
```

Как мне достать функцию в которую я передаю параметры и её внедрить?

Пробовал через useDispatch(), но ничего не вышло.

Нужно сделать для этого input `onChange`:

```
<InputBase
    placeholder="Search"
    value={searchValue}
    classes={{
       root: classes.inputRoot,
       input: classes.inputInput,
    }}
    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно завести локальный стейт:

```
// redux стейт
const searchValue = useSelector(state => state.Search.searchValue)
// локальный стейт
const [value, setValue] = useState(searchValue)

const handleChange = event => {
    setValue(event.target.value)
}

return (
    <InputBase
        placeholder="Search"
        value={value}
        classes={{
           root: classes.inputRoot,
           input: classes.inputInput
        }}
        inputProps={{"aria-label": "search"}}
        onChange={handleChange}
    />
)
```